# conditional line-by-line reading from file

Tags: c++, while-loop, conditional-statements

For now I have that code:

```
if (minimizator_weighted) {
    while (dataFile >> t >> e >> sigma) { // read data file value by value
        /* some code */
    }
}
else {
    while (dataFile >> t >> e) { // all the same but will not read standard deviation
        /* almost the same code */
    }
}
```

As you can see the only difference between `if` and `else` flows is the condition of `while` loop. I wonder if there any possibility to optimize that snippet and re-use the code? It would be great if I could write some kind of:

```
while ((minimizator_weighted) ? (dataFile >> t >> e >> sigma) : (dataFile >> t >> e)) { ... }
```

but I don't sure if that trick is correct... Could you advise me some optimizations? Thank you!

**EDIT**
Here is the full code snippet

```
if (minimizator_weighted) {
    while (dataFile >> t >> e >> sigma) { // read data file value by value
        data_set::pt point;
        point.t = t;
        point.e = e;
        point.c_vis = 0.0;
        point.c_invis = 0.0;

        if (std::abs(sigma) <= GSL_SQRT_DBL_MIN) // check for division-by-zero error
            sigma = 1.0;

        point.sigma = sigma;

        set.curve.push_back(point); // store point

        data_numPoints++; // collect some stats
        set.curveAvg += e;
    }   
}   
else {
    while (dataFile >> t >> e) { // all the same but will not read standard deviation
        data_set::pt point;
        point.t = t;
        point.e = e;
        point.c_vis = 0.0;
        point.c_invis = 0.0;

        set.curve.push_back(point);

        data_numPoints++;
        set.curveAvg += e;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You're asking us to make a judgement about whether you can use "some code" in place of "almost the same code". Since we haven't seen the code in either of these blocks I can confidently say no one will be able to provide you with a good answer.

Comment: is the sigma value in the file anyway? If so, you'll have to read it and ignore it conditionally.

Comment: @RichardHodges no. in the first case (weighted) data files consist of lines with 3 `double` values per line. in the second case (unweighted) data files consist of lines with 2 `double` values per line. you can see that I do no ignoring while reading those files

Comment: No, this code should not be combined. I would suggest that since only the `minimizator_weighted` version of `data_set::pt` uses `sigma` that you create 2 objects one with a `sigma` member and one without. Write extraction operators for each, then templatize the function this loop resides in, and templatize `set.curve` thereby correctly streamlining the loop.

Comment: @JonathanMee I can edit the loop body and add extra `if`-statement to track weighted and unweighted cases. If we're dealing with weighted case I will store the sigma value. In other case I will simply ignore sigma value (as my other code do)

Comment: @DrobotViktor Welp, I couldn't cram a response in a comment, so I decided to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41125514/2642059 You can do this with nested if statements, but if you're still early enough in design that you could consider rearchitecture I've tried to spell out what would need to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a level of indirection

```
bool read_data_line1(istream& dataFile, T& t, E& e, Sig& sigma)
{ return dataFile >> t >> e >> sigma; }

bool read_data_line2(istream& dataFile, T& t, E& e, Sig&)
{ return dataFile >> t >> e; }

auto read_data_line_func = minimizator_weighted ? read_data_line1 : read_data_line2;
while(read_data_line_func(dataFile, t, e, sigma))
{
    data_set::pt point;
    point.t = t;
    point.e = e;
    point.c_vis = 0.0;
    point.c_invis = 0.0;

    if (minimizator_weighted)
    {
      if (std::abs(sigma) <= GSL_SQRT_DBL_MIN) // check for division-by-zero error
        sigma = 1.0;
      point.sigma = sigma;
    }

    set.curve.push_back(point); // store point

    data_numPoints++; // collect some stats
    set.curveAvg += e;
}
```

Comment: wow, thank you, interesting solution! But why we can't use ternary operator directly?

Comment: Can't say I'm a fan. putting an `if`-statement inside a loop seems worse.

Comment: @JonathanMee I leave such worries to the branch predictor on my machine. Sometimes you have to be pragmatic.

Comment: @DrobotViktor You can use the ternary expression directly, as long as the function signatures match. But the net result is the same (and I find it more readable personally)

Comment: why do you use `auto` type instead of `bool`?

Comment: @DrobotViktor I use `auto` for type deduction. I can't use `bool` since I mean to store a function pointer. You can use the type `bool(*)(istream&, T&, E&, Sig&)` directly, but I find this more verbose.

Comment: @StoryTeller so would be my example in top post correct?

Comment: @DrobotViktor Without compiling, I'd venture a guess that it would be correct. Both operands evaluate to `istream&` eventually, and it's guaranteed to be short circuited (only the single expression you need will be evaluated).

Comment: @DrobotViktor Yes the ternary in the loop condition is a simpler way to handle this, but note that you have added a branch in the conditional and a branch in the body of the loop. This is not an ideal solution.

Comment: Thank you for your perfect explanations!

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd express it something like this:

```
data_set::pt collect_point(std::istream& is, bool minimizator_weighted)
{
    data_set::pt point;
    is >> point.t >> point.e;
    point.c_vis = 0.0;
    point.c_invis = 0.0;
    if (minimizator_weighted) {
        is >> point.sigma;
        point.sigma = std::max(point.sigma, GSL_SQRT_DBL_MIN);
    }
    return point;
}

void test()
{
  int data_numPoints = 0;
  data_set set;

  while (dataFile)
  {
    auto point = collect_point(dataFile, minimizator_weighted);
    auto e = point.e;
    set.curve.push_back(std::move(point)); // store point
    data_numPoints++; // collect some stats
    set.curveAvg += e;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your architecture shows us 3 things that are wrong:

1. `sigma` is an unused variable for some objects
2. Object behavior is dictated by an external variable (`minimizator_weighted`)
3. `minimizator_weighted` must be used every-time one of these objects is accessed

These are fundamental design flaws that are not just costing you here but throughout your program. The fix is going to demand rearchitecture though. Let me show you how to do that and you can make your decision of whether you want to just keep working around the problems or fix the architecture.

To start with you need *2* fundamental types, the 1<sup>st</sup> will match with the `data_set::pt` that you've already defined without `sigma` then we'll extend it with `data_set::pt_weighted` to add the `sigma`:

```
struct pt {
    double t;
    double e;
    double c_vis;
    double c_invis;
};

struct pt_weighted : pt {
    double sigma;
};
```

Now we'll write extraction operators, again starting with an extraction operator for `data_set::pt` and extending it for `data_set::pt_weighted`:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& lhs, data_set::pt& rhs) {
    rhs.c_vis = 0.0;
    rhs.c_invis = 0.0;

    return lhs >> rhs.t >> rhs.e;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& lhs, data_set::pt_weighted& rhs) {
    lhs >> static_cast<data_set::pt&>(rhs) >> rhs.sigma;

    // check for division-by-zero error
    if(std::abs(rhs.sigma) <= GSL_SQRT_DBL_MIN) rhs.sigma = 1.0;

    return lhs;
}
```

From here you'll need to start working with templates. To start with you'll need to templatize `set.curve` to be either a container of `data_set::pt` or `data_set::pt_weighted`, then your functionality will need to change to:

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
    for(T point; dataFile >> point;) {
        set.curve.push_back(point); // store point

        data_numPoints++; // collect some stats
        set.curveAvg += point.e;            
    }
}
```

If you can't establish `minimizator_weighted` until runtime you'll need to call `foo` like:

```
minimizator_weighted ? foo<data_set::pt_weighted>() : foo<data_set::pt>();
```

Comment: almost agree with you, but ew - those templated function calls. Maybe take the destination pt/pt_weighted as a reference argument, or tag, or maybe `SetType::typename point_type`?

Comment: great example, thank you! I'm a bit new to CPP and object-oriented programming so C paradigms are still strong enough

Comment: @RichardHodges Hmmm... if `minimzator_weighted` isn't determined until runtime, how would you approach this? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your suggestions but I don't see how they help me get around the templatized function call.

Comment: @JonathanMee I think I'm saying that I prefer ADL to explicitly specialised template functions. With ADL there's no need to perform precision logic surgery if you choose to add a new type.

Comment: @RichardHodges I don't feel like I can understand your point from 600 characters or less. I've opened a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41128744/2642059 in case you care to come clarify.